# Multiple instances of one service

Tags: angular7

I have a simple service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CompToCompService {
  private data = new Subject<any>();
  data$ = this.data.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  Send(value: any) {
    this.data.next(value);
  }
}
```

I use it to sling some light data back and forth between components. 
I have however found myself needed to use it twice in the same component to send data and use different components to listen. As angular services are now by default singletons everything is being jumbled together.
Is it possible to create different instance of the server and if so how do I get the listening components to listen to the right instance?

If not what's the best way to accomplish what I am trying to do. I am trying to avoid creating a tiny service like that for every piece of communication I need to do. I know of `events` but my communications are across the `routing-outlet` and events don't seem to like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a parent component with two or more child components.
in each child component use

> providers: [serviceName]

Then you will have tow instance of service .
but you must work with each instance in their component